# Base-60 arithmetic on the *nix command-line

Tags: time, command-line, base-60

What's the easiest way to calculate with a mixture of time-amounts (base 60) and other amounts?  I want to be able to ask questions like:

- What's 2 hours 15 minutes and 25 seconds divided by 42.195?  (answer given in hours minutes and seconds for example)

My current workflow for that kind of question is to convert all the time-amounts into seconds, do the maths, then convert back again, but there must be a decent tool to do that for me?  Some argument to `bc` perhaps?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha seems to handle this kind of thing quite well: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=What%27s+2+hours+15+minutes+and+25+seconds+divided+by+42.195

Comment: Yes, its output contains "3 minutes 12.56 seconds" which is a perfect answer.  I'd really prefer something (a) command-line, and (b) not requiring internet access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`units`](https://www.gnu.org/software/units/) tool:

```
$ units "(2 hours + 15 minutes + 25 seconds) / marathon" "minutes/km; seconds/km"

    3 minutes/km + 12.558415 seconds/km
```

Comment: Ha!  This is perfect.